# How to align a div vertically?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```css
#image-text {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
}
#mission-picture{
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mission-picture">  
          <div id="image-text">
            <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is how the text should be display if done correctly:
https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-redline.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score -1):

You can add `display:flex; align-items:center` to `#mission-picture`

```css
#mission-picture{
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `display: flex;` to `#mission-picture` and `margin: auto 0;` to `#image-text`

```css
#image-text {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center; */
  margin: auto 0;
}

#mission-picture {
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="mission-picture">
  <div id="image-text">
    <h2>Our Mission</h2>
    <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the reason for downvoting aswell.

Comment: thanks, it worked

Comment: Please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for. Happy to have an upvote aswell